# Compound class names not permitted error, Selenium, Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

My tests passed. Soddenly it gave an error after Chrome update. After what I add  dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>    and System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");  before Webdriver,
```

Now My tests some passed but some I got this error

org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names not permitted
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#invalid_selector_exception
Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you have

```
By.className("x y z")
```

where X, Y, and Z are class names. Change it to

```
By.cssSelector(".x.y.z")
```

`By.className()` takes only a single class and you've passed it more than one. Change it to a CSS selector or remove all but one class name.